# 0x fail on Optimism network

Tags: 0x

Recently, I try to swap token with 0x on Optimism network.

But some transactions were fail. At first, I thought it was due to insufficient estimatedGas. But it not work when I set a larger number.

I've traded 0x with both Matic and AVAX and they haven't had any problem.

Is there anything I might not have noticed?

---

I use /swap/v1/price? to get the price, like : https://optimism.api.0x.org/swap/v1/price?sellToken=0x68f180fcCe6836688e9084f035309E29Bf0A2095&buyToken=0x7F5c764cBc14f9669B88837ca1490cCa17c31607&sellAmount=10000000

and then use swap/v1/quote? to get the data and send the transactions.
like :https://optimism.api.0x.org/swap/v1/quote?buyToken=0x68f180fcCe6836688e9084f035309E29Bf0A2095&sellToken=0x7F5c764cBc14f9669B88837ca1490cCa17c31607&sellAmount=3000000000&slippagePercentage=0.01

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have the allowance set correctly and are sending to the correct contract, on Optimism the address is different. It's returned in the `to` field and you can confirm in the [protocol docs](https://protocol.0x.org/en/latest/basics/addresses.html#exchange-proxy-addresses) and also in the [contract-addresses package](https://github.com/0xProject/protocol/blob/development/packages/contract-addresses/addresses.json#L493).

After that try setting the `takerAddress` parameter with your address, this will run additional validation and provide a more accurate gas estimate.